# Authorize.net - request rejected by fdc omaha -invalid transaction type

Tags: php, payment, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

We are integrating authorize.net CIM payment gateway.

When we process credit card payment in sandbox mode it's working fine but in live mode, we are getting following error 
**"request rejected by fdc omaha -invalid transaction type".**

Does anyone experience the same issue earlier.If yes please advise how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using test mode in the sandbox?  If that is the case, then your request is not correct.  It would help if you included your entire request with sensitive information redacted.

Comment: No its working fine in sandbox(developer account) or testmode(live account).But in Live mode I am getting above mentioned error

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem with your live account.  Contact Customer Support.